# mongodb - how to lock collection with mongodb java client

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I need to update a whole collection concurrently in a background thread, but read operation might take place at the same time. It takes about 3 seconds to update the collection when I benchmark it. Is there any way to lock a collection while updating the collection?  I try to create a new collection and insert all the documents into it and rename it to the original collection with "dropToTarget=true", but I am not sure how safe and stable it is in terms of sharding. I read that renameCollection is incompatible with the sharding.

It would be great if someone can suggest if there is a good idea.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do that dropping the old collection data is OK? Could you version your data with a field?

Comment: We don't use old data, so we don't want to keep it in the db. And we always provide users with new data.

Comment: My question was around how it's used. If you tagged data with a version, you could write the new data, update clients to read from that version, and then at the next update, delete the oldest version.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought about the option, but the client wouldn't know the version unless the client retrieves the version from somewhere(from another collection). Then the client needs to access this collection to get the version first. I just wanted to make this area simple, but if there is no option, i would take this approach.

Comment: What is the "client" in this case? Web servers or...? (As it could be cached for a certain number of seconds, minutes, or triggered based on this collection update....)

Comment: yes. I would say web server.

Comment: To prevent unnecessary collection creation and global write locks, I'd suggest going with the idea of a version as periodically checking for a new version.

Answer (score 0):

Do you presented two possible strategies to update your collection, one being inline with a lock on it and the other one with a temporary collection?

As the mongodb documentation clearly states it will not work for sharded collections (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/). From my understanding this means that your collection you want to rename isn't sharded, as you need to delete the other collection before you do the actual renaming you'll mostlikely loose any previously kept sharding (-information). So you would need to reactivate the sharding. I highly discourage from using the two collection approach, especially if you're sharding your data.
You would need to get all the data from your sharded collection and store it centralized, once you're done with updating you need to rename the collection and shard it again. This will cause much I/O for your whole system, especially for the client doing the update.

Depending on your system architecture (with a single point of entry). You could easily hold some global flag telling you if you currently have the collection update running. Forbidding other write operations.
For multi-entry points into your MongoDB you might try $isolated, but this doesn't work with sharded collections. And I'm not sure if it allows read operations, the documentation isn't very clear.

Is it strictly disallowed to write any data, while the update is in progress? What type of updates do you perform. Can they influence each other? Or would it be possible to have concurrent writes?

Comment: The client is not going to write or update the data. It's only read-only from the client side. Only my backend component updates or writes once a day with new data. I would like to delete all the data and insert it daily. So when I delete all data/write new data, I want to have client wait or read new data instead of old data.
I don't want to take the approach for renaming the collection. That's why I am trying to figure out a way to lock a collection.